# Prepopulating mulit select picklist from url using pagereference in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In salesforce I am trying to build a url that will prepopulate a multi select picklist in a form. Basically, you press the New Meeting button on an account, which redirects to a New Event. The PageReference redirect returns a PageReference instance with the url that contains the parameters for preopulation. However, the multi select picklist is only being populated with the first selection. For example:

String of the built URL:

```
url = 'https://cs11.salesforce.com/00U/e?00NZ0000000LdLp=401%28a%29&00NZ0000000LdLp=401%28k%29';
```

The field ID for the multi select picklist is 00NZ0000000LdLp, which is repeated in the URL above, thus populating the chosen fields as 401(a) and 401(k)

The redirect method then returns:

```
return new PageReference( url );
```

When I click the New Meeting button, only 401(a) will be chosen. If just copy and paste that built URL into the address bar, both 401(a) and 401(k) will be chosen. Why does the PageReference cut out the data?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might have to do with the way that the page reference stores url parameters. It stores those parameters in a map which means if you repeat a param name multiple times it will get overwritten. It would do the equivilent of:

mapParams.put('00NZ0000000LdLp','401(a)');
mapParams.put('00NZ0000000LdLp','401(k)');

You might be better off adding the url parameters yourself and doing something similar to below.

PageReference ref = new PageReference(url);
ref.getParmeters().put('00NZ0000000LdLp', '401(a)&00NZ0000000LdLp=401(k)');

Above is just a suggestion though. I am not sure how the url escapes are going to affect this idea but to answer your original question I think that the use of maps in the PageReference object is likely why you are only getting one selected value.